# How to make a reproducible iso file with mkisofs/genisoimage?

Tags: rsync, mkisofs, reproducible-build

In an automated process an iso file is created with `mkisofs`. 
Even, as the original data is excactly the same, the resulting iso files are not the same (their `md5sum` changes). Since I `rsync --checksum` the result, I dislike that the "same iso" is of course retransferred every time. I expect mostly timestamps to be the main difference.

Is there some `libfaketime` buildin switch to generate an iso via `mkisofs` that would indeed be the same.

I do not know if only timestamps matter? I have compared the resulting iso files with their `xxd isofile` output like this:

```
diff --side-by-side  --suppress-common-lines <(xxd a.iso) <(xxd b.iso )
```

and there seem to be only 51 lines representing 16 Bytes (so roughly 800 Bytes of difference) in the else exact same file.

The command used to generate this iso in question is roughly this:

```
genisoimage -o "file.iso" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
    -J -R -v -T -V 'CDLABEL' "datadir/"
```

BS: Am I missing a command line parameer switch with `rsync` that does checksumming for ~1MB chunks of big files, as to prevent the retransfer when as in my case only some 800 bytes differ?

Comment: rsync usually checks parts of files to optimise updates, but not if they are both apparently local (eg on nfs). Add `--no-W` to force it. There is a `libfaketime` and `faketime` utility to emulate the system clock by using `LD_PRELOAD` (if not setuid).

Comment: Hi, I just published a new version of `schilytools`. The included enhanced `mkisofs` includes support for reproducible time stamps. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First an important note: Do not use `genisoimage` as it is a defective variant of a `mkisofs` from May 2004.

In the time up to May 2007, plenty of Debian specific bugs have been added and since then it is dead.

The important thing to know here is that `genisoimage` creates defective filesystem images that at some time may no longer be accepted by your OS...

The official `mkisofs` is however still actively maintained and fixed plenty of non-Debian specific bugs on August 2006. There are currently no known bugs.

Now to your problem: You are using -R (Rock Rigde) and this adds `UNIX` like timestamps to the files meta data. This is problem number 1....

The other problem is that the ISO-9660 filesystem super block (officially called primary_descriptor) contains the creation date and the modification date. The latter can be controlled via the option `-modification-date`.

If you believe this is a really needed feature, I could add a similar option for the creation date. Then you however still would need an option to tell the Rock Ridge formatting part to use the modification date of the files instead of the time of the last read access.

Frequently updated versions of the original source are part of the `schilytools` tarball that can be retrieved from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

The currently latest schilytools tarball introduced support for reporducible ISO-9660 filesystem images. Please fetch/compile/install schily-2020-03-27.tar.bz2.

There are a few new options:

- `-noatime` tells `mkisofs` to archive the modification time as atime.
- `-creation-date` sets the creation date in the PVD
- `-expiration-date` sets the expiration date in the PVD
- `-effective-date` sets the effective date in the PVD
- `-reproducible-date` sets all times except for `-effective-date` and `-noatime`in addition.

This works for vanilla ISO-9660 filesystem images as well as for images that contain `Rock Ridge` and `UDF`. 
See the recent man page at: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html

Your updated command line would look this way:

```
mkisofs -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
  -J -R -v -T -V 'CDLABEL' \
  -reproducible-date=20200327 "datadir/" > file.iso
```

Answer (score 5):

People switched to [xorriso](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/) as [one might want to avoid mkisofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrtools#License_compatibility_controversy) and genisoimage seems to not be developed any further.

[To make the xorriso output reproducible set the environment variable named SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to the same value as seconds since January 1st 1970.](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/man_1_xorriso.html#ENVIRONMENT)

You can either use xorriso directly or its [mkisofs compatibility mode named xorrisofs](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/man_1_xorrisofs.html).

```
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 xorrisofs YOUR-MKISOFS-ARGS
```

Comment: more options for xorrisofs: `-uid 0 -gid 0 -dir-mode 0755 -file-mode 0644 -volid "SOMETHING" -preparer "" --gpt_disk_guid 00000000000000000000000000000000 --set_all_file_dates set_to_mtime --modification-date=1970010100000000 -input-charset utf8 -path-list files.txt`. files.txt must be sorted with `LC_ALL=C sort`. unset envs HOME and MKISOFSRC. verify with `TZ=UTC 7z l *.iso`

Answer (score 0):

Provided answers didn't work for me, but with help from some friends I figured out a way to create reproducible ISO images from arbitrary folders, with xorriso

Date has to be exported as an environment variable. File permissions can be different for different people, so we force them to something. `preparer_id` will vary because by default it includes xorriso's full name with version. `uid`/`gid` can also be different on different systems.

This script accepts path to folder as a launch argument, or as prompted input. Haven't tried for OS image creation though.

```
export SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH="$(date -d20010101 -u +%s)"
output_filename=result.iso
file_mode=0444

folder="$1"
while [ ! -d "$folder" ]; do
    [ -z "$folder" ] || printf "'%s' not a directory?\n" "$folder"
    read -p "Enter path to dir containing files to pack: " folder
done
list="$(mktemp)"
(cd "$folder"; for f in *; do printf "%s\n" "$f=$PWD/$f"; done) \
    | LC_ALL=C sort >"$list"

xorriso \
    -preparer_id xorriso \
    -volume_date 'all_file_dates' "=$SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH" \
    -as mkisofs \
    -iso-level 3 \
    -graft-points \
    -full-iso9660-filenames \
    -joliet \
    -file-mode $file_mode \
    -uid 0 \
    -gid 0 \
    -path-list "$list" \
    -output "$output_filename"

rm -f "$list"
```